# Regular expression to match linux path

Tags: python, regex

I have tried many regular expressions found in stackoverflow like: [This](https://regex101.com/r/t5uwwO/1)

```
import re

mystring = """
some string /bin/path and also /opt/something/bin/. 
Some other string /home/user/file.extension. 
Some more string \.out and \.cpp and \.extension. 
All these are paths and needs to be captured.
"""
```

I wanted to use python `re.sub` to replace all paths with word `PATH`.

```
output = """
some string PATH and also PATH. 
Some other string PATH. 
Some more string PATH and PATH. 
All these are paths and needs to be captured.
"""
```

Comment: Why this is not treated as ``/bin/path`` PATH ?

Comment: @PySaad: Edited the question. Thanks for the catch

Comment: Your regex doesn't match any of the paths

Comment: @azro: exactly thats the very reason I posted this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
mystring = re.sub(r'[/\\](?:(?!\.\s+)\S)+(\.)?', r'PATH\1', mystring)
print(mystring)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7v9nE7/1).

Comment: What an easy one ^^ I tried many thing and I was at `((?:[/\\]\.?[a-z]+)*(?:[/\\](?:\.?[a-z]+)+|[\\/]))` :D nice

Comment: Great. Why ``\1`` in ``PATH\1`` ?

Comment: @azro: Thanks :-)

Comment: @PySaad: because of a possible dot in the end.

Comment: @Jan: Wow great answer. Cheers